# How to show an infinite feed of data in Watch App?

Tags: ios, watchkit, wkinterfacetable

How can in Apple Watch App I can create a never ending scrolling content fetched from the web?

One way is to use [WKTableInterface](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceTable_class/index.html), with each row as full screen image and the last row as a button with "Load More" action. On "Load More" action I can fetch more data and use below method to insert rows with new data.

```
- insertRowsAtIndexes:withRowType:
```

Is this a good approach? Can I fetch and add rows without user tapping on "Load More"?

Instead, can I use a vertical page based navigation style? I think no becaue pages have to be known beforehand. Right?

Comment: Doesn't Apple recommend keeping UI interactions with the Watch short (on the order of 10 secs, I seem to remember)?

Comment: Thanks @Drux for the pointer. So you mean no feed like interfaces, makes sense? Can you point out any video/doc where they said/mentioned something similar?

Comment: Have posted relevant quote below. I'd have to do more research for determining how it applies in this particular context. I guess you are better placed to do that perhaps based on the quote/link.

Answer (score 1):

A "Load More" button is really your only option since there's no "did scroll" kind of callback or delegate method.

Also from the [Apple Watch Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/Tables.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH14-SW4):

> For tables that require more rows, consider loading only a subset of
>   rows initially and then provide the user with controls to load more
>   rows.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is the quote (from [*Apple Watch Human Interface Guide*](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/WatchHumanInterfaceGuidelines/)) that I had in mind re "seconds":

> WatchKit app complements your iOS app; it does not replace it. If you
>   measure interactions with your iOS app in minutes, you can expect
>   interactions with your WatchKit app to be measured in seconds. So
>   interactions should be brief and interfaces should be simple.